# Bundling in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a question regarding bundling in react native. I am creating separate style files for my views. Suppose I have two views with same style. Will it load twice or bundling will create a single js file for all views and it will be considered only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the styles are in single file, It will be bundled only once.

Comment: Can I verify this?

Comment: Check the bundle file. But, It will be difficult to verify. I heard this in some conference speech. I forgot which conference it is.

Comment: Ok. Actually I am looking for some performance improvement in my app.